# Содержит ли данный код UB?

Tags: c++, операторы

Содержит ли данный код UB?

```
int i = 6;
i = 7, ++i, i++;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Такие операторы, как **оператор запятая**, **оператор логического И (&&)** и **оператор логического ИЛИ (||)** перед вычислением следующего операнда выполняют все побочные эффекты, связанные с выражением для первого операнда.

Например, вы можете написать

```
std::cout << ( i++, i++, i++ ) << std::endl;
```

или

```
if ( i++ > 0 && i++ < 10 ) { /* ... */ }
```

или

```
if ( i++ == 0 || i++ % 3 == 0 ) { /* ... */ }
```

То же самое относится к **спискам инициализации в C++**. Например,

```
int a[] = { i++, ++i };
```

Или в конструкторе класса

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int y;

    A( int i ) : x( i++ ), y( ++i )
    {
        //,,,
    }
};
```

Если поведение перечисленных операторов относительно  побочных эффектов одинаково и в C++, и в C, то относительно списков инициализации между этими двумя языками имеется **важное отличие**. В C порядок вычисления побочных эффектов инициализаторов в списке инициализации не определен.

Из стандарта C (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 23 The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the
>   order in which any side effects occur is **unspeciﬁed**.152

Сравните эту цитату с цитатой из стандарта C++ (8.5.4 List-initialization)

> 4 Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. **That is,
>   every value computation and side eﬀect associated with a given
>   initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side eﬀect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in
>   the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.** [Note:
>   Thisevaluationorderingholdsregardlessofthesemanticsoftheinitialization;
>   forexample, itapplies when the elements of the initializer-list are
>   interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily
>   there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. —end
>   note]

Answer (score 11):

Нет, никакого UB тут нет, если учесть, что группировка операторов и операндов в этом выражении имеет следующий вид

```
(i = 7), (++i), (i++);
```

Оператор "запятая" упорядочивает (sequences) как вычисление значений своих операндов, так и выполнение их побочных эффектов. (Выражаясь старой терминологией, оператор "запятая" является *точкой следования*).

Сначала будет вычисляться левый операнд, а затем - правый. Причем все побочные эффекты вычисления левого операнда возымеют место еще до того, как начнется вычисление правого операнда.

> **5.19 Comma operator [expr.comma]**
>
> **1** [...] A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression. Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. [...]

Answer (score 5):

С чего бы это?

Операция `,` однозначно определяет порядок (слева направо) вычисления выражений, результатом будет значение последнего выражения.

У вас `i` станет равно 9.